# merge large data frame multiple times exhausts memory

Tags: r, dplyr, out-of-memory, left-join

I'm trying to filter a large data frame twice `(DF1 and DF2)` and then merge the two filtered data frames into one data frame `(DF1+DF2->DF3)` many times and combine the results  into a single data frame `(DF=DF3[1]+DF3[2]...DF[n])`, but keep running out of memory (8Gb). The initial and final data frames easily fit on a laptop so its the processing that exhausts memory.

What method is fastest and requires least memory? Should I run the code in parts and recombine, get a bigger gun, or is this a job for a relational database or `MapReduce`?

The code below illustrates the problem.

```
#create combination df
Combn <- data.frame(t(combn(as.vector(rep(LETTERS[1:26])),2))) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character)

#create data df
Nrows <- 1000000
Data <- data.frame(Symbol=rep(LETTERS[1:26])) %>% 
  mutate(Symbol=as.character(Symbol)) %>% 
  bind_rows(replicate(Nrows-1,.,simplify=FALSE)) %>% 
  arrange(Symbol) %>% 
  group_by(Symbol) %>% 
  mutate(Idx=seq(1:Nrows)) %>% 
  mutate(Px=round(runif(Nrows)*20)) 

FnPDList <- function(Combn,Data){      
  Dfs <- list()      
  for(i in 1:nrow(Combn)){
    print(i)
    Symbol.1 <- Combn$X1[i]
    Symbol.2 <- Combn$X2[i]

    Sym.2 <- Data %>% 
      filter(Symbol==Symbol.2) 

    Df <- Data %>% 
      filter(Symbol==Symbol.1) %>%
      left_join(Sym.2,by="Idx",suffix=c(".1",".2"))

    Dfs[[i]] <- Df
  }      
  return(Dfs)
}

#splitting into n parts works
X <- FnPDList(slice(Combn,1:10),Data)
Z <- do.call(bind_rows,X) 

#trying to solve in one go exhausts memory
X <- FnPDList(Combn,Data)
Z <- do.call(bind_rows,X)
```

Comment: take a look at data.table https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf  , used and really good performance.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look, are data tables more memory efficient?

Comment: I suggest the use of cloud service, such as GCP. The instance, 16Cores104GB memory VM, doesn't cost me a dollar per hour.

Comment: thanks, yes this would work, but I'd prefer a laptop type solution if possible

Comment: I think `data.table::merge` can be used on regular `data.frames` without conversion, and that performance is better

Comment: you're not splitting in n parts, you're just taking the first 10 rows of your combinations, so you end up with a 10 million rows data.frame, which is not that much. The data you're trying to build will have 325 million rows, that might be too much for your system regardless of how you build it, do you really need all of it or are you going to filter or aggregate it afterwards ?

Comment: I think there are two issues, 1) analysing a large data frame that won’t load into memory, and 2) manipulating a data frame already in memory. 
Is a relational database best for (1)? 
For (2) I can create ``Data`` with 208m rows (setting ``Nrows=8000000``), but I run out of memory creating ``X``. So although ``Data`` loads, it can’t be manipulated using the function – is there another way like slicing, parallel processing etc?
Once ``X`` is created I need to analyse firstly each combination (can be individually), and secondly the last ~30 rows for all combinations.

Comment: In addition to data.table, also check out feather. [Here is a benchmarking blog for fwrite vs rds vs feather](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/the-r-data-i-o-shootout/)